# ShareKit - How can I share links without leaving the app?

Tags: ios, sharekit

I am trying to use ShareKit in my iOS app. I just want to know can I share contents without leaving the app? For example: User has iOS 5 and want to share content via Facebook. In that situation ShareKit opens Safari and the content is shared on it. But I want the content is shared in my app without leaving app. Is it possible? Thank you.